# Fallout Shelter Quest rooms

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'n starting off on early quests in Fallout Shelter.

Inside the quest destinations are rooms that are blanked out by brickwork, hoarding etc and you can't see inside them or get your quest party in there.  I've cleared every room, defeated all enemies, spoken to any characters and the room is still blocked & the only option is to return home.  On the first Paula quest this room opened itself but I don't know how.  On the second one there is no key but there's a blocked elevator which I guess goes into it.  How do I get in?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a room is unlocked (accessable) if you are inside a room next to it. For normal rooms this (with a door left and right) enables the next horizontal room. Elevators enable every surrounding room - horizontal und vertical. A room is accessable if there is a green border around the black background. Rooms can only be at these black backgrounds. Brickwork is handled like the underground side-walls: no way through.

Spoiler to find the key:

> The key is located inside a lootable container. You can find them by clicking on the shiny boxes, cabinets, cupbouards, tables...

Comment: i just came back from this first Paula quest. i can confirm that i have checked each and every shiny containers in this vault, yet the room is still unaccessible. is there any action sequence mandatory in getting the key to such rooms?

Answer (score 0):

The one quest that has a key is the exception. In all other quest buildings, all inaccessible metal/dirt areas are just that, and there are no rooms there.

The "designers" of these buildings are clearly not experts on space efficiency, especially given their elevator placement.